# AppleScript to open apps based on "last opened"

Tags: applescript

I have a simple AppleScript that opens certain "housekeeping" applications that I have created.

Can I update it so the applications are opened only if they haven't been opened in the past 24 hours?

Many thanks!

```
tell application "Finder"
    open application file "clean-exports.app" of folder "Applications" of startup disk
    open application file "clean-queue.app" of folder "Applications" of startup disk
    open application file "clean-dropbox.app" of folder "Applications" of startup disk
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to write a timestamp to `UserDefaults`. Then compare it with the current timestamp and run the applications if the difference is greater than 86400 which is 24 * 3600 seconds

```
use AppleScript version "2.5"
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

on runApplications(timestamp)
    tell application "Finder"
        open application file "clean-exports.app" of folder "Applications" of startup disk
        open application file "clean-queue.app" of folder "Applications" of startup disk
        open application file "clean-dropbox.app" of folder "Applications" of startup disk
    end tell
    do shell script "defaults write com.paul.clean 'timestamp' -float " & timestamp
end runApplications

set currentTimestamp to current application's NSDate's timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
try
    set savedTimestamp to (do shell script "defaults read com.paul.clean timestamp") as real
    if currentTimestamp - savedTimestamp > 8.64E+4 then
        runApplications(currentTimestamp)
    end if
on error
    runApplications(currentTimestamp)
end try
```

After running the applications write the current timestamp to disk.

The file in UserDefaults is located in `~/Library/Preferences/com.paul.clean` (~ represents your home folder). The name `com.paul.clean` is arbitrary but reverse dns form is recommended